# Angular: Catch a 404 error on file not found

Tags: angularjs, promise

In my Ionic project I am creating a function to find out if a file exists locally or not. I have created the following function:

```
$rootScope.eventFieldTemplateExists = function(field) {
    //var templateUrl = 'views/fields/' + field.name + '.html';
    var templateUrl = 'views/fields/testfile.html';


    $http.head(templateUrl).then(function(res) {
      console.log("success");
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("catch");
      console.log(err);
    });

    return true;
};
```

The file `testfile.html` does not exist. The above works fine when I enter a file that do exist, but I still get a console error when the file does not exist:

```
HEAD http://localhost:9000/views/fields/testfile.html 404 (Not Found)
catch
{data: "", status: 404, config: {…}, statusText: "Not Found", headers: ƒ}
```

Is there some way to suppress the error? I was hoping that the `.catch` would suppress it, but apparently it does not.

Comment: apart from error, why are you using `http head`, it will respond  without the response body. I would have used `http get` instead

Comment: Why do you want to remove HTTP error from console ?

Answer (score 0):

A response with status `404` will invoke the promise's rejection handler, this is the expected behavior, but your code does not include it so control goes strait to `.catch`.

Include a rejection handler and resolve the response [`.when`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)

```
$http.head(templateUrl).then(function(res) {
    // this will run for status 2xx
    console.log("success");
    console.log(res);
}, function(response) {
    // this will run for status 4xx, 5xx, etc..
    if (response.status === 404) {
        return $q.when("404: file not found, but it's ok")
    }
    return $q.reject(response);
})   
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log("catch");
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all errors in a `$http` request with a second parameter for `then()`.

```
$http.head(templateUrl).then(function(res) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(res);
}, function(err) {
    console.log("catch");
    console.log(err);
})
```

---

AngularJs `$http.head` works like this:

```
$http.head('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

[Documentation on $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods)